# Running a piped unix command from a Tcl script

Tags: tcl

I am trying to run the following:

```
exec tail CRON_GBOI_INC_AVG_COMPRESS_20140425_18* | grep -i "status of" | awk -F" " '{ print $NF }'
```

What it does is it tails the file, `grep` for the line containing the text `status of`, which will return a string and then return the last character in the string.

However, Tcl always throws the following error:

`missing close-bracket or close-brace` while compiling that line.

How can I change the code to do what I need to achieve? Is it at all possible with Tcl?

Answer (score 1):

Tcl's syntax is not the shell's syntax. The conversion of that line would be:

```
exec tail {*}[glob CRON_GBOI_INC_AVG_COMPRESS_20140425_18*] | \
        grep -i "status of" | awk "-F " {{ print $NF }}
```

That's to say, the globbing is explicit, the double quotes are round whole words, and the single quotes are changed to braces. (It's also broken over 2 lines with a backslash-newline sequence for clarity.)

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working for me. This is the error message I get `extra characters after close-brace while compiling "exec tail {*}[glob CRON_GBOI_INC_AVG_COMPRESS_20140425_18*] | grep -i "status of" | awk -F" " {{ print $NF }}..."` I also tried your syntax of `awk "-F "` which also doesn't work. `

Answer (score 0):

Sirs, 
    As it happens, Tcl string handling may make this easier:-

```
set stringBack [exec tail [lindex $argv 0] | grep -i "[lindex $argv 1]" ]
set wanted [string index $stringBack end]
puts "stat chr is $wanted"
```

.

We run as, say,

```
./charget /path/to/file 'text hook we choose'
```

with file and text hook as parameters (quoting the text hook string for handoff to grep insensitive).